# Filtering a R datatable subtable

Tags: r, filter, datatable, tags

I have a shiny app with a dataframe displayed as a datatable. Filtering is enabled and working fine. However, some of the data are tags, and every object has several tags, resulting in a very large table with a lot of redundant data. What I would like to do is to aggregate the tags in a subtable (or another way) but still be able to filter for every tag.

My data is similar to this:

```r
df <- data.frame(name=c(1,1,1,2,3,3), color=("blue","blue","blue","red","green","green"), tags=c("fine","awesome","cute","sweet","cute","fine"))<br/>

output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable ({
datatable(df, filter = 'top')
})
```

My datatable looks currently like this:

| name | color | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | fine |
| 1 | blue | awesome |
| 1 | blue | cute |
| 2 | red | sweet |
| 3 | green | cute |
| 3 | green | fine |

What I would like it to look like is something similar to this:

| name | color | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | fine, awesome, cute |
| 2 | red | sweet |
| 3 | green | cute, fine |

I can get this by using aggregate:

```r
df <- aggregate(tags ~., df, toString)
```

however, I then cannot filter the tags seperately anymore, e.g. filter for everything tagged "fine" and "cute". Is there any other way to make the tags filterable while not having to have a row for every tag? Alternately, is there any way to affect the filtering?
Additionally, is there any way to change the default filter from *AND* ("blue" *AND* "green") to *OR* ("blue" *OR* "green")?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired table like this

```
df <- data.frame(name=c(1,1,1,2,3,3), color=c("blue","blue","blue","red","green","green"), tags=c("fine","awesome","cute","sweet","cute","fine"))

library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
    group_by(name, color) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(trimws(paste(., collapse = ','))))

output <- DT::renderDataTable({datatable(df1, filter = 'top')})
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me! I have since realized my problem is more with how DataTable filters content and have included a workaround using selectInput.